# Use jailbroken iPhone as webserver

Tags: ios, jailbreak, webserver, 32-bit

I know that this already has an answer, it is outdated. I am running iOS 10.3.3 on an iPhone 5 (so its 32 bit), and I want to run a web server for no reason at all. I have tried install lighttpd and php, but I can't find a way to turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `ios-lighttpdphp-mysql` from the repo https://cydia.angelxwind.net/ and turn on the server in settings. Then open 
`http://localhost` in Safari and your iPhone is now a webserver with PHP and mySQL.

This should work on all iOS versions and devices.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/2g20ma/how_can_i_turn_my_old_jailbroken_iphone_into_a/)